# How to customize the content view of the NSDrawer?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

My requirement is a drawer without the border along the 3 sides of the content view.

Comment: Unfortunately i think there is no easy way to fulfill my requirement because the portion of code that draws the borders for the drawer is private. I've tried to use `class dump` to figure out which private methods of `NSdrawerFrame` are responsible for this but i have not understood. Out of curiosity... Does anyone know an alternative to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a window, then attach it as a sub window to the main window.

In order to make it stick to the main window, you would have to listen to notifications about changes to the main window's frame and move your sub window around sync'ed with the changes in the main window.